# Facebook Api Integration with Java Application

Tags: java

I have downloaded restfb Jar for connecting to facebook.I want to use this api in my java application to connect Facebook.I am developing a desktop application for this purpose.I have created account on Face book and registered as a developer.
I want The likes comments and friendslist
Is it possible to connect Facebook from my java application?

If yes please, can some one send me the example code for that and treat me as a New Bee in this facebook integration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "treat me as a New Bee" Collect nectar, produce honey, serve the queen

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Here, we generally prefer more specific questions, rather than asking for a tutorial/example/resource type questions. See [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [allowed topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for some more details

Comment: Can someone sent the examples regarding the same .